# What DVI splitter cable do I need?

Tags: video, dvi, cable

I have a Dell Precision T5400, with a single graphics output port. In the box came a splitter to split it to two standard monitor cables. I have two monitors with DVI inputs, so I'd rather use those, but I'm unsure what splitter I should be looking for.

Essentially I need to get from this:

[image: Current DVI(?) splitter]

to two of these:

[image: Monitor DVI plug]

Can anyone tell me what I need to buy?

Answer (score 4):

That's a [DMS-59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59).

> DMS-59 is a 59-pin electrical connector generally used for computer video cards. It provides two DVI or VGA outputs in a single connector. An adapter cable is needed for conversion from DMS-59 (digital) to DVI (digital) or VGA (analog), and different types of adapter cables exist. The connector is four pins high and 15 pins wide, with a single pin missing from the bottom row, in a D-shaped shell, with thumbscrews.

As for adapters, a quick search for "DMS-59 to DVI": [http://www.amazon.com/Dell-DMS-59-Y-Splitter-Refurbished-H9361/dp/B000MJ31TG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MJ31TG)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a standard DVI Splitter will work for your application. You need to have the same input and output video format. I would recommend converting the input to the same format that you have on your monitors and then use a splitter.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using a Splitter the DVI input and output connector types need to be the same. That is DVI-D Single or Dual link for both the inputs and outputs.